# HMaster is automatically stops in hbase

Tags: linux, apache, hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I installed and configured Hadoop (version 2.7.0) & HBase (version 1.2.3) in pseudo distributed mode. I test hadoop with a test program (Word Count) and every things is OK. Before I enter Hbase shell and get list of tables, Hmaster is running, but When I enter hbase shell and get list of tables (or create table), i see this Error:

```
hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE

ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null
Here is some help for this command:

List all tables in hbase. Optional regular expression parameter could
be used to filter the output. Examples:

hbase> list


hbase> list 'abc.*'
hbase> list 'ns:abc.*'
hbase> list 'ns:.*'
```

And When i back from Hbase shell and get jps, I see that there is no HMaster running but HRegionServer and Zookeeper are still running.

Here is my Hbase-site.xml Configuration:

```
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Here is my core-site.xml Configuration:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
 </property>

 <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
 </property>
</configuration>
```